# Illustrator: saving as SVG gives an empty file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, artboard

When I save an artboard as SVG, I get an empty file. I made sure there are no objects outside the artboard in the same layer.

When I paste the shape in the newly created SVG from the source AI file, save it and open it again I get the image below.

I guess browsers don't care about where the artboard is, since it's displayed well in my browser. But it is a pain to do these extra steps. Is there a solution for this, or what am I doing wrong here?

[image: weird behavior]

Comment: What happens then when you drag the artwork(circle), to the artboard and save that as svg?

Comment: the same - align the circle in the middle of the artboard, save the svg and close it, open the file again: same sesult.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to **File > Save As** and select `SVG` in the menu options, make sure that *Use Artboards* is not ticked.